# boto s3 - How to find url or IP of connection

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I want to use this code to connect to S3

```
conn = S3Connection('<aws access key>', '<aws secret key>')
```

But I then receive an error: socket.error: [Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

The reason may be that I am behind a proxy server, so I need to know the IP address of the connection in order to open ports.

So the question is, how can I know that IP, or url ( I know that the IP may vary for each connection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding proxy authentication to [S3Connection](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html) and everything works as expected